# Radius of Curvature of Curve $r^2=a^2\cos 2x$

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

What is the radius of the polar curve
$$r^2=a^2 \cos2\theta$$ at any point (r, $\theta$) using the expression of the radius of curvature of polar curves i.e.
$$R= \frac{(r^2+r_1^2)^{3/2} } {r^2+2r_1^2-rr_2} $$

Comment: I guess that $r_1=r'$ and $r_2 = r''$. Have you tried deriving the equation $r=a \sqrt{\cos 2\theta}$ and plugging it in the expression for $R$?

Comment: @Ernie060 $r_1$ is indeed $r'$ and yes i have tried it but it's coming out impossible to simplify even one bit

Comment: Do you necessary want to use this expression for $R$? Alternatively, you can express the polar curve in cartesian coordinates. You'll see that it is a circle, and you can read the radius right out the equation.

Comment: @Ernie060 Well not necessarily but I don't see how that's a circle? Isn't a circle $r=a$ in polar form?

Comment: My mistake! I am not really awake yet. You're right, the curve is not a circle!.

Comment: Anyhow, I've just put the formula for $R$ in Mathematica, and I found that $R=\frac{a}{3 }\sqrt{\sec(2\theta)}$. This is a nice answer. So basically your problem is to do the algebra?

Comment: @Ernie060 I guess. Yeah. You may even post a photo of it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/83208/discussion-between-ernie060-and-archit-jain).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to do some part of the algebra. Deriving $r=a\sqrt{\cos 2\theta}$ using the chain rule gives $r'=-a\sqrt{\sec 2\theta}\sin 2\theta$. To find the second derivative we use both the product rule and chain rule. Bring both terms on the same denominator and you should get
$$r''=-a \frac{3+\cos 4\theta}{2(\cos 2\theta)^{3/2}}.$$
Here we have used a double angle formula for $\cos$.

Then it's a simplification using trigoniometry. For instance, the fact $r^2+(r')^2$ should become $a^2 \sec 2\theta$. You can find this by puttin the terms on the same denominator and then using the main formula of trigoniometry: $\cos^2 \theta + \sin^2\theta = 1$.

The answer should be $R= \frac{a}{3}\sqrt{\sec 2\theta}$.